# How can create a vertical dash line in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't want use any library if you can write code for my question Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: there is no built-in solution - most likely you need a `CustomPaint`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink Thanks for Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
class DashedLineVerticalPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double dashHeight = 5, dashSpace = 3, startY = 0;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    while (startY < size.height) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, startY), Offset(0, startY + dashHeight), paint);
      startY += dashHeight + dashSpace;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

usage:

```
CustomPaint(
painter: DashedLineVerticalPainter(),
size: Size(1, double.infinity)))
```

Comment: try `Canvas.drawPoints` (with `PointMode.lines`) - it will be faster